# vpn for my smart TV

Tags: vpn, wireless-router, netflix

I am looking to connect my Samsung smart tv into a VPN connection in order to get American tv porgrams on netflix.

Unfortunately there is no app on the TV for VPN.   On my laptop I use HMA which I pay about 7$ a month and with that I just download software and it just installs and runs on windows, giving me the functionality I need.

Its becoming a bit of a chore to connect my laptop into the tv everytime I want to watch something on the american netflix esp when changing channels etc.

I share an internet connection that is a wifi adsl router.. like a standard one you get from your broadband provider...

What im wondering is if I could buy a router that has VPN software built in then connect that in the middle of the wifi router and my tv meaning that it does not intefere with other people using the wifi but when I want to use the vpn I just plug the tv into the router and then the router into the adsl wifi hub?

... or am I barking mad?

Comment: Yes.  If you want your TV to use a VPN then you require a router that supports connecting to a VPN in order to provide that functionality to devices that might not support it.

Comment: All routers with the Free Open Source Software called DD-WRT (or Openwrt) can do that. You may Google it. Also, you may consider the fact that some producers, like Buffalo, sell routers with DD-WRT already installed (there are others, you will have to look them up, can't remember off hand).